# Sending variable through _POST on boostrap modal

Tags: javascript, php

Im making a timeline app in php that allows to add, edit and delete events. I wanted to use a modal to ask for confirmation and to test this function from boostrap, but then my problem happened, as i cant make it send a variable through a form.

this calls the modal for each event:

```
<button type="button" class="eliminarEventoModal" data-id="<?php echo $evento['id'] ?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminarEvento">
```

this gets the $evento['id'] from before into #idEvento, i got from other post on this page related to modals, and i know it works

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".eliminarEventoModal").click(function() {
     $("#idEvento").text($(this).attr('data-id'));
     $("#eliminarEvento").modal("show");
  });
});
</script>
```

this is the modal code. it ask if you are sure to delete or not. if not, the modal close and nothing happens, if yes, then push a form to editEvento.php (a diferent file where i use the modal) where the event is deleted.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="eliminarEvento" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="eliminarEventoLabel">Delete event</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Confirm delete event.</p>
        <?php $idEvento='<span id="idEvento"/>'; echo "a".$idEvento."a";?> //<--- line to test if getting the right id only
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <form class="col-md-auto needs-validation" method="POST" action="/editarEvento.php" >
                <input type="hidden" name="borrar" value="borrar">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $idEvento;?>"> //<--- line where it dont work
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The form works with the borrar variable, but not with the id, but why? i need the id to delete the event, so i cant delete any. i have tried some other posts from this page, but i didnt get to work. i have no experience with javascript, im thinking my problem may be related misunderstading some part related to it.

--Edit: modal from page source

```
<div class="modal fade" id="eliminarEvento" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="eliminarEventoLabel">Eliminar evento</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Confirmar eliminar evento.</p>
        a<span id="idEvento"/>a     </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <form class="col-md-auto needs-validation" method="POST" action="/Aeberion/editarEvento.php" >
                <input type="hidden" name="borrar" value="borrar">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<span id="idEvento"/>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In the page source in the browser, what is the actual value for that `<input>` element?  Did PHP successfully echo the value you expect?

Comment: In the line just under "Confirm delete event", the echo idEvento it does shows the correct value, but dont show the second "a". but in the input, i dont know why it breaks.

Comment: What specifically is the resulting page source for this same code snippet?

Comment: this code should you take to the file editarEvento.php if you confirm in the modal. im not sure if its what you asked

Comment: The code shown is mostly HTML, but includes some PHP `echo` statements.  Your *first step* in debugging this is to look at the page source in your browser and see if those statements actually output what you expect.  Since the problem being described is that the form isn't posting the values you expect, this question will also need to contain that complete output.  For the entire "modal" shown above, please include the exact resulting HTML from the page source for that "modal".

Comment: i edited the original post with the HTML. im new to debugging with PHP, so i may be slow at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<span id="idEvento"/>">
```

The `<>` brackets in the `value` attribute are breaking the overall parsing.  If you really want the `value` to be an entire HTML element, you need to [HTML-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) the output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlentities($idEvento);?>">
```

Though it's not clear *why* you want the `value` to be an HTML element, because the information it contains is essentially meaningless and already known to you.  But if that's the value you want it needs to be encoded so the HTML parser doesn't think it's part of the `<input>` element.

---

What it really looks like though is that *this* is the value you want:

```
$evento['id']
```

Which you assign to a `<span>` here:

```
$("#idEvento").text($(this).attr('data-id'));
```

However:

- A `<span>` is not posted to the server as part of a form
- You want *the value*, not an empty copy of a `<span>` element.

You already know how to find an element by its `id` and set a property on it:

```
$("#idEvento").text($(this).attr('data-id'));
```

So give your target element an `id` so you can set its value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="eventoModalId">
```

and:

```
$("#eventoModalId").val($(this).attr('data-id'));
```

Comment: its not that a i want to have an html element, i want a php variable. i have tested your solution, and i think the problem comes from the use of <span >, which gets taken into the variable as a whole instead of only the content. i think i may need to use another way to achieve that?

Comment: @fcojosesanchez: I've updated the answer.  It looks like the value you *want* is `$evento['id']`.  I don't see why you're trying to involve a `<span>` at all, but if the value you want is from the `data-id` of the selected button then just set the value of the `<input>` to exactly that.  The same way you do with the text of the `<span>`.

Comment: yes, now it works, thanks you. one last question, why in the input you used id="eventoModalId" instead of value="eventoModalId"?

Comment: @fcojosesanchez: So the element can be identified by an id, just like you were already doing with the span element.  Why on Earth would you want to set the *value* to that?  Don’t you want the value to be the value from the data-id on the button?  Overall you seem fairly confused about what it is you’re actually trying to do…

Comment: yes, i have been trying to improve my skills in php and html for a while testing some functions of boostrap,, thats why im confused with some aspects.